# xrdp started but not listening

Tags: xrdp

I'm trying to get xrdp working on 18.04 and it appears to be running but is not listening.

```
:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
[ ok ] Restarting xrdp (via systemctl): xrdp.service.
:~$ tail /var/log/xrdp.log
[20190208-23:15:07] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_VSOCK cid -1 port 3389)
[20190208-23:15:50] [DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3389.
[20190208-23:15:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20190208-23:15:52] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 887
[20190208-23:15:52] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20190208-23:43:45] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_VSOCK cid -1 port 3389)
[20190208-23:43:45] [DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3389.
[20190208-23:43:45] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20190208-23:43:47] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 1707
[20190208-23:43:47] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
:~$ sudo lsof -i :3389
:~$ sudo netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " | grep ":3389"
:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
:~$ sudo systemctl list-units | grep xrdp
  xrdp-sesman.service  loaded active running   xrdp session manager
  xrdp.service         loaded active running   xrdp daemon
:~$ sudo netstat -antup | grep xrdp
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350    :::*     LISTEN      894/xrdp-sesman
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What were the steps you took for setting up xrdp?

Can you check to make sure xrdp is not only running but enabled by running:

```
sudo systemctl status xrdp
```

Based on your output it looks like it isn't yet enabled. To fix that use:

```
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
```